# Greatest values in a column for multiple categories -- oracle11g

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

Here is the `LOCATION1` table:

```
Loc_id     Loc_name      Loc_state   Loc_area
1          ABC              IA         600
2          DEF              FL         700
3          GHI              FL         900
4          JKL              IA         200
5          MNO              NY         600
6          CXY              IA         600*  
.
.
```

Now, I want a list with `greatest loc_area` for each `loc_state` and the associated `loc_name`. So, the output can look like this:

```
Loc_State     Loc_Name     Max(Loc_area)
IA              ABC           600
FL              GHI           900
NY              MNO           600
```

I think it starts with the following but I don't know if this is correct.

```
SELECT LOC_STATE, LOC_NAME, LOC_AREA
FROM LOCATION1 LOC1
WHERE LOC_AREA IN (
SELECT MAX(LOC_AREA)
FROM LOCATION1 LOC2
HAVING LOC1.LOC_STATE = LOC2.LOC_STATE
GROUP BY LOC_STATE);
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

The above query gives multiple `loc_name` with same `loc_state` and `max(loc_area)`.

Assuming there there is a **CXY** `loc_name` in **IA** `loc_state` with same `loc_area` of **600***.

So the output can have both 
`(IA, ABC, 600)` and 
`(IA, CXY, 600)`.

I guess this is acceptable as a `loc_state` can have multiple `loc_area(s)` with same value, in this case **600** but in different `loc_name(s)`.

**So, problem solved!**

I think a_horse_with_no_name's solution also works fine.

```
select loc_state, loc_name, loc_area
from location1 loc1
where loc_area = (select max(loc_area)
                  from location1 loc2
                  where loc1.loc_state = loc2.loc_state);
```

Thanks again!

Comment: "*I don't know if this is correct*": what happened when you ran it?

Comment: Your query is just right: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a126c/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial statement was half way there, co-related condition isn't quite right though. And you don't really need the `IN` or the `group by` in the inner query.

So your initial statement should probably look like this:

```
select loc_state, loc_name, loc_area
from location loc1
where loc_area = (select max(loc_area)
                  from location loc2
                  where loc1.loc_state = loc2.loc_state);
```

One alternative to this would be to using a window function to avoid querying the table twice:

```
select loc_state, 
       loc_name,
       loc_area
from (
  select loc_state, 
         loc_name, 
         loc_area,
         dense_rank() over (partition by loc_state order by loc_area desc) as rnk
  from location
) t
where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't return max value for each loc_state, although it returns distinct loc_state(s).

Comment: @anupk: you tried what? The first or the second statement? Please show us some sample data (edit your question, don't put this into a comment) that shows that it "doesn't return the max value". As far as I can tell, both return exactly what you asked for: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a126c/6

Comment: @anupk: if you use `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank()` in the seconde query, you can get rid of the "duplicates" with the same area. You should add another column to the `order by` of the window definition in order to get consistent results the, e.g. `order by loc_area desc, name asc`.